# Where to trigger Modal-components in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a list of items in my app. When the user clicks on a list item I want to show more details in a . I could put the details-component into the list item component and hide it by default.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will only be displaying a single `Modal` at a time. You can create the Modal component outside of the list and set it to visible on click of the list item. So you code will be something like this.

```js
class YourComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    showModal: false,
  };

  render() {
    const items = [1, 2, 3];
    return (
     <View>
       <View>
         {
           items.map((item, i) => {
             <Button key={i} onPress={() => this.setState({ showModal: true, item }) title="Open Modal" />
           })
          }
       </View>
       <ReactNative.Modal visible={this.state.showModal}>
         <Text>{ this.state.item }</Text>
       </ReactNative.Modal>
     </View>
    );
  }

}
```